# Processing files in specific order

Tags: python, filenames, date

I have 40k images in a folder.  The file names follow the following pattern:

```
1558058263_18ea873ddcf8c65e.jpg
1558408930_63c29ce4462ec194.jpg 
1558062887_18ea873ddcf8c65e.jpg
```

In this the first part of the file name is the time stamp and the second part is the machine id that generated the image.

I want to process each of these files in a sequential order based on only the  time stamp.  How can I take the files sequentially for processing.  I am using python3 for selecting the files.  The current code is as follows:

```
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                for name in files:
                        img=fr.load_image_file('/home/ubuntu/faces/' + name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you could use the `sort()` or `sorted()` functions (from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670029/can-i-force-python3s-os-walk-to-visit-directories-in-alphabetical-order-how)):

```python
# ...
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
   files.sort()
   for name in files:
      print(name)
```

or

```
# ...
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
   for name in sorted(files):
      print(name)
```

Comment: Ah! Yeah, since the timestamp numbers are all the same length / number of digits, then sorting lexicographically will also work.

Comment: @jeffschaller thank you...the files.sort() works as required.

Comment: Do keep in mind that this is a simplistic sort and will do the wrong thing in late November of 2286, about 267 years from now, when the timestamp becomes 11 digits long. Keep [L. Scott Johnson's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524206/117549) around for when that comes!

Answer (score 2):

You might try sorting via a lambda (UNTESTED):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in sorted(files,  key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group())):
        img=fr.load_image_file('/home/ubuntu/faces/' + name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` command should give you what you want.

```
ls | sort -n -t '_' -k1
```

`-n` sorts numerically, instead of the default lexicographically.
`-t '_'` specifies `_` as a field separator.
`-k1` sorts on the first field.

Comment: That looks like shell commands, not python.

Comment: The OP didn't specify they wanted a Python solution. If that's the case, this should be in Stack Overflow, not here.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and it worked fine

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" 2>/dev/null| sed "s/\.\///g"| awk -F "_" '{print $1,$2}'| sort -k1| awk 'OFS="_" {print $1,$2}'
```

Will update with Python script asap